# Setting up Caliburn.Micro v2.0.0 in Windows Phone 8 App Development

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I have tried setting up v2.0.0 of Caliburn.Micro for Windows Phone 8 Development. There is a call for a method called Start() in the AppBootstrapper class that does not have a definition.
Deleting this does not help the cause as the application does not navigate to the MainPage.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Start` with `Initialize`.